# Open sub-tree click area

Tags: javascript, jstree

By default, when you open a sub-tree, you have to click on the little triangle on the left.

Is it possible to change the click behavior so that you can click anywhere on the name?  Technically, this is really how about make the `<li></li>` element clickable that same way the icon is clickable.

Comment: How about posting some code and what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your jstree to do this when you init the jstree. In your select_node event for the node type you want to expand when clicked use the following:

> this.toggle_node(e); 
>   return false;

For example:

```
types: {
    'root': {
        select_node: function (e) {
            this.toggle_node(e);
            return false;
        }
    },
    'default': {
        select_node: function (e) {
            alert('Node selected');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Any nodes that are of type root will expand when clicked, while any nodes you have marked as default will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Just move the code for registering the click handler from the image to the `li`. If the expanded tree is inside the `li`, you might need to ensure that the click hit only the li and not a subnode by checking the event's `target`.